# Target expected a batch of elements where each example has shape [1]

Tags: tensorflow.js

I try to programm a neural network predicting soccer results with tensorflow in node.js but i seem to lack basic understanding of what i am really doing. All numbers i am getting don't make any sense.

So basically I just want to input the results of the last 100 games and then get a prediction for any matchup. I dont know how to do this properly. I tried to train it by passing in following testdata:

[  1    0     0     0     1     0     2      3    ...   1 0 0  0 1 0]

T1   T2  T3 T1 T2 T3 S1 S2

So first i pass which team was the home and which team was the guest team, followed by the score of the home and the guest team. At last I pass which matchup I want the prediction for. The example starts the list of the last 100 matchups with a game where team 1 (home) played against team2 (guest) and it ended 2:3. Followed by many other results between the 3 teams and then with the last 6 elements in the array I pass that I want a prediction for team1 against team2.

What do I have to do? And why do I get the error in the title? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```

class AI2{

```
//Compile model
compile(){
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.embedding({inputDim: 23, inputLength: 806, outputDim: 2}))
    model.add(tf.layers.globalAveragePooling1d({}))
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 16, activation: 'relu'}))
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}))
    model.summary()
    model.compile({optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy']});
    
    return model;
}

async run(){
    const model = this.compile()

    let loInputData: any[] = []
    let loOutputData: any = []

    let teams = [
        {name: "TAK",rating: 10},
        {name: "TUS",rating: 7},
        {name: "Bipfel",rating: 2}
    ]

    for(let u=0; u<1000; u++){

        let loSingleTestData: number[] = [] //[806]
        
        while(loSingleTestData.length < 800){
            for(let p=0; p<3; p++){
                for(let g=0; g<3; g++){
                    if((p!=g) && (loSingleTestData.length < 800)){ 
                       let goals2, goals1 = 0

                        goals1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 * teams[p].rating/teams[g].rating)
                        goals2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 * teams[g].rating/teams[p].rating)
                        
                        if(p==0){loSingleTestData.push(1,0,0)}else
                        if(p==1){loSingleTestData.push(0,1,0)}else
                        if(p==2){loSingleTestData.push(0,0,1)}

                        if(g==0){loSingleTestData.push(1,0,0)}else
                        if(g==1){loSingleTestData.push(0,1,0)}else
                        if(g==2){loSingleTestData.push(0,0,1)}

                        loSingleTestData.push(goals1, goals2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        loSingleTestData.push(1,0,0,0,1,0)
        loInputData.push(loSingleTestData)

        let goals2, goals1 = 0
        goals1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 * teams[0].rating/teams[1].rating)
        goals2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 * teams[1].rating/teams[0].rating)
        
        loOutputData.push([goals1, goals2])
    }

    model.fit(tf.tensor(loInputData), tf.tensor(loOutputData), {
        epochs: 100,
        callbacks: [
            tf.callbacks.earlyStopping({monitor: 'val_acc'}), 
            new tf.CustomCallback({onEpochEnd: (epo)=>{
                console.log("EPOCH RUN SUCCESSFULLY")
                console.log(epo)
            }})
        ]}).then(()=>{

        const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor([loInputData[0]]))
        prediction.print()
    })
}
```

}

let ai = new AI2()
ai.run();

I tried creating some random data just to test it, please excuse this mess of a code.